# Archive in Xcode11 not showing in organizer even though status is succeeded

Tags: xcode, archive

no (scarcely found) solutions from other threads helped, reason being (I think) that they were about different versions of Xcode. The issue seems prevalent throughout the versions, but solutions are sadly not.
So I run Product->Archive in my Xcode (version 11.3.1, which I run on macOS 10.15.3, beloved Catalina). In the build bar status is Succeeded (yay!), but after I go to (very intuitive location) Window->Organizer, then only despair remains, as there are no archives there.
Options in product scheme regarding archiving are checked.
Apart from archiving, app builds and runs and it is signed using my Developer id.
When I create brand new (and empty) project, then archiving is successful, but this information does not help me in the least.